# json boolean gets converted to string

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following .json (saved as a file named: settings.json):

```
[{"compact": false, "noPadding": true}]
```

On click, I want to change the boolean for "compact" to its opposite state. This is
my function to do it (theres a little bit of react in there, but i think it shouldnt matter for my question):

```
onClick={editJson(this, "settings", "compact", this.context.settings[0]["compact"], !this.context.settings[0]["compact"])}
```

Which performs the following function:

```
function editJson(component, filename, field, oldvalue, newvalue) {
    var json = component.state[filename] || [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if (json[i][field] === oldvalue) {
            json[i][field] = newvalue
        }
    }
    $.post('json/write.php', {filename: filename + '.json', data: json}).then(function (data) {
        queryJson(component, filename);
    });
}
```

Which then writes back to my .json by performing write.php:

```
<?php
file_put_contents($_POST['filename'], json_encode($_POST['data']));
return ($_POST['data']);
```

But now my booleans have become strings (which I dont want):

```
[{"compact": "true","noPadding": "true"}]
```

I assume the problem is either with javascripts weak typing or my php, but i cant figure out the solution.

**How can I keep my booleans as booleans in this scenario?**

Comment: POST data is always a string. You may need to loop over the data and cast or just cast them individually before encode.  It would be easier to cast 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that POST data is always a string. That's just how it works...

But you could iterate through your POST data and use PHP's [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to convert the strings to boolean

```
filter_var(YOUR_POSTDATA, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```